# socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10060]

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to connect to a printer by tcp. I am able to connect, I am able to send a command, but I am not able to read from the socket.

This is the code:

```
$command = "...";

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec" => 20, "usec" => 0));
$connection =  @socket_connect($socket, '192.168.1.100', 9100);

if( $connection ) {
    echo 'ONLINE<br>';
    socket_write($socket, $command, strlen ($command)) or die("Could not write output\n");
    $read = socket_read($socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ) or die("Could not read input\n");;
    echo $read;
    socket_close($sock);
}
else {
    echo 'OFFLINE: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error( $socket ));
}
```

I am sure I am connected. If I do not call `socket_read`, I can see "`ONLINE`" on screen.
If I call `socket_read` function, this is the message I get:

> socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10060]

Comment: My crystal ball says you forgot to send a newline character after the command

Comment: I tried with this command: "02 48 50 48 50 48 48 50 52 50 03" . "\n" without success

Comment: Have you gotten this to work any other way? How do you know it is a correct command?

Comment: I am not sure about the command. I am trying this printer. What I know by the docs is that if the command is written wrong, the printer should response with an error message.

Comment: Are you sure you are meant to send a zero character, two character, space character, four character, etc...? Are you sure it doesn't mean to send a character with ASCII value 02, ASCII value 48, ASCII value 50, etc...? 02 and 03 would be control characters, and the bytes in the middle spell out a number (020200242), which is awfully suspicious

Comment: Probably you are right, but I am not sure cause the docs are unclear. Anyway I tried with 020200242, but I get the same error.

Comment: did you include the 02 and 03 bytes as well?